# localStorage.clear() isn't working with ternary in react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm playing around with local storage can't seem to get this to work this is very simple just to play around with it but the code.

```
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

const favorite = () => {
     setIsFavorite(!isFavorite) ? localStorage.setItem('name', search[0].title) : localStorage.clear() 
}

return(
 <button onClick={favorite} className="favorite">Favorite: {isFavorite ? <FaHeart /> : <FaRegHeart />}  </button>

)
```

Why is is that on the initial click the value is stored but when clicked again localStorage.clear() is not being run, can it not be used in a ternary operator or am I just using it wrong?

Also I have tried switching the order in the ternary but it doesn't seem the .clear() ever gets called.

Comment: You are passing function reference to your onClick handler in the button dom node, you should call the favorite using an arrow function. ```onClick={()=>favorite()}```

Comment: @Amr it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: I was going to ask why that mattered in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get the new value separately. You should not count on a set hook value. Secondly, the ternarnik for the call functions is not pure code - use if else. Good luck in studying React.

```
const favorite = () => {
     const newFavoriteState = !isFavorite;
     setIsFavorite(newFavoriteState)
     if (newFavoriteState) 
       localStorage.setItem('name', search[0].title)
     else
       localStorage.clear() 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response so it seems the ternary is not always the solution hahah. Also is the "Good luck studying React" a back handed compliment?..

Comment: @Brandon.b Not at all, this is a sincere wish)

Answer (score 0):

```
setIsFavorite(!isFavorite) ? localStorage.setItem('name', search[0].title) : localStorage.clear()
```

This code is more or less equivalent to:

```
const x = setIsFavorite(!isFavorite)
if (x) localStorage.setItem('name', search[0].title)
else localStorage.clear()
```

What does the the `setIsFavorite(!isFavorite)` return? Probably not the value you expect.

Try using it separately

```
setIsFavorite(!isFavorite);
!isFavorite ? localStorage.setItem('name', search[0].title) : localStorage.clear();
```